# Media queries in styled-component declared with object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I write styled components like in `react-native`, as a `js` object:

```
const SectionTitle = styled.div({
  fontSize: '25px',
  display: 'flex',
})
```

Is it possible to use media queries with the above object style?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. You just need to wrap your object keys with quotes to form a string from a media query rule.

For example:

```
const SectionTitle = styled.div({
  fontSize: '25px',
  display: 'flex',
  '@media(min-width: 788px)': {
    fontSize: '40px'
  }
})
```